# How to display harizontal tabs vertical in ionic3 angular project

Tags: angular, ionic3

How can i display harizontal tabs in my ionic3 project vertically.`Below is my html and typescript code.

```js
export class TabsPage {
 tab1Root = PatientPage;
 tab2Root = ExpensesPage;
 tab3Root = EventcalendarPage;
 tab4Root = ContactPage;
 constructor() {
 }
 ionViewDidLoad() {
 }
   ionViewDidEnter(){
    /* tabs hide when keyboard open in Android */
     // this.keyboard.onKeyboardShow().subscribe(()=>{document.body.classList.add('keyboard-is-open')})
     // this.keyboard.onKeyboardHide().subscribe(()=>{document.body.classList.remove('keyboard-is-open')})
 }
}
```

```html
<ion-tabs class = "convert">
  <ion-tab [root]="tab1Root" tabTitle="Patients" tabIcon="md-contacts"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab2Root" tabTitle="Expenses" tabIcon="md-cash"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab3Root" tabTitle="Appointments" tabIcon="md-clipboard"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab4Root" tabTitle="Contact" tabIcon="md-contact"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

`

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the `tabs` component doesn't seem to work well in a vertical layout, at least not without some scss overrides and hacks :/

I followed [the solution found by Chris Griffith](https://chrisgriffith.wordpress.com/2017/08/03/vertical-tabs-in-ionic/)

Using `ion-split-pane` you can split your layout:

```
<ion-split-pane when="xs">

        <ion-menu [content]="content" class="c-sidenav">

            <ion-content>
                <button ion-button large block clear icon-only (click)="togglePage('Page1')">
                    <ion-icon name="md-list"></ion-icon>
                </button>
                <button ion-button large block clear icon-only  (click)="togglePage('Page2')">
                    <ion-icon name="md-pin"></ion-icon>
                </button>
            </ion-content>

        </ion-menu>

        <ion-nav [root]="rootPage" main #content></ion-nav>

    </ion-split-pane>
```

Adjust the width with the scss variables in the `variables.scss` :

```
$split-pane-ios-side-min-width: 70px;
$split-pane-ios-side-max-width: 70px;
$split-pane-md-side-min-width: 70px;
$split-pane-md-side-max-width: 70px;
$split-pane-wp-side-min-width: 70px;
$split-pane-wp-side-max-width: 70px;
```

And manage the routes in the `app.components.ts`, something like:

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { App, Config, Nav, Platform } from 'ionic-angular';

import { Settings } from '../providers/providers';

import { MainPage } from '../pages/pages';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app.html'
})
export class MyApp {
  @ViewChild(Nav) nav: Nav;

  rootPage = MainPage;
  isPage1: boolean = true;
  isPage2: boolean = false;

  constructor(platform: Platform,
              settings: Settings,
              private config: Config,
              private app: App) {
    ...
  }

  ...

  togglePage(whichPage: string): void {
    this.isPage1 = false;
    this.isPage2 = false;

    let newTab: string = '';

    switch (whichPage) {
      case 'Page1':
        this.isPage1 = true;
        newTab = 'Page1Page';
        break;
      case 'Page2':
        this.isPage2 = true;
        newTab = 'Page2Page';
        break;
    }

    this.nav.setRoot(newTab);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to show vertical tabs, you can just use `split pane` component and the `sidemenu` which always remains `open`.

Alternatively, here is one approach to do this: [vertical tabs in ionic](https://chrisgriffith.wordpress.com/2017/08/03/vertical-tabs-in-ionic/)